# Precalculating MD5

Tags: md5

I've got MD5 hash of one million symbols password and I've got first 999,992 symbols. I need to bruteforce last 8 digits. Can I precount first symbols' hash (let's call it base hash) and then just brute 8 chars length string and add its hash to base hash to make finding right pass faster? What algorithm should I use or what software can help me?

Comment: You're talking about one password that's a million characters long, not a million different passwords, right?

Comment: Yes. One password which contains one million charachters. I know hash and all chars except last 8 and want to find right password fast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that's possible.  MD5 is based on the [Merkle-Damgård construction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merkle%E2%80%93Damg%C3%A5rd_construction), which performs the hashing in blocks.  You can hash a number of blocks, then save the state of the hash function and use it as the starting point to try different possibilities for the remaining blocks.

Based on the documentation (I haven't tested), I *think* calling `clone()` on a Java [`MessageDigest`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/security/MessageDigest.html) will copy the current state of the hash function.  You could use that to build your partial hash from the known characters, then create a clone for each guess.  That's assuming that the MD5 implementation actually supports cloning.  There's a chance (depending on what language and library you use) that you might have to write your own MD5 implementation.

---

Note that MD5's block size is 512 bits (64 characters), and the length of your password (one million) is a whole multiple of that.  That means your password characters will completely fill up the last block of data, and the hash function will need an *additional* block for padding.  So you'll precompute the partial hash of the first 999,936 characters that you know, then produce the final data block from the remaining 56 characters that you know plus the 8 that you're guessing, then append the padding block after that.

An implementation like Java's `MessageDigest` should take care of the details of dividing things into blocks, though.  You can *probably* (again, I haven't tested) just create a `MessageDigest`, call `digest(byte[])` with your 999,992 known bytes, and then call `clone()`.

Comment: But I haven't got much time and I need to brute only 1 password. Are there any programms or libraries which can do it?

Comment: Not that I know of, but I've never gone looking.  This site is about programming, not password-cracking, so I'm addressing your programming question, not your need to crack a password.

Comment: I tried to hash 999936 symbols, hash 64 symbols (8 last digits=0) and then add each 8 bytes of first hash to each 8 bytes of the second. The answer doesn't equal hash of full 1 million password.

Comment: That's not how it works; you can't combine hash values in any meaningful way.  Create a hash object, feed it everything except the last 8 bytes, then clone the hash object and feed the last 8 bytes into the cloned hash object.  *Then* take the final hash value and compare it against your target.